# Reading special characters from Byte[]

Tags: c#, .net

I'm `writing`  and `reading`from Mifare - `RFID` cards.

To `WRITE` into the card, i'm using a `Byte[]` like this:

```
byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(txt_IDCard.Text);
```

Then, to `READ` from the card, I'm getting some error with `special characters`, when it's supposed to show me `é, ã, õ, á, à...` I get `?` instead:

```
string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
string result2 = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
string result3 = Encoding.UTF7.GetString(buffer);
```

e.g:  Instead I get `Àgua, amanhã, você` I receive/read `?gua, amanh?, voc?`.
How may I solve it ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds4kkd55.aspx

Comment: Don't the values of `result`, `result2`, and `result3` look different? Further, if you wrote the data in the `ASCII` format you'd have to read it back in the same.

Comment: You need to find out what encoding the `byte[]` was originally created with if you wish to decode it - you need to use the same encoding.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud yes, in the `result2` it's reading from `ASCII` the same encoding it's writen. But all of the results looks the same.

Comment: @Oded as you can see i Used `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string)` to get the string and turn it into a `Byte[]` when I do the reverse `Byte[] to Strin` it does not work ;\

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ASCII by its very definition only supports 128 characters.

What you need is ANSI characters if you are reading legacy text.

You can use `Encoding.Default` instead of `Encoding.ASCII` to interpret characters in the current locale's default ANSI code page.

Ideally, you would know exactly which code page you are expecting the ANSI characters to use and specify the code page explicitly using [this overload of `Encoding.GetEncoding(int codePage)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wzsz3bk3.aspx), for example:

```
string result = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(buffer);
```

Here's a very good reference page on Unicode: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

And another here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05tb6tz%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

**But maybe you can just use UTF8 when reading and writing**

I don't know the details of the card reader. Is the data you read and write to the card just a load of bytes?

If so, you can just use UTF8 for both reading and writing and it will all just work. It's only necessary to use ANSI if you are working with a legacy device which is expecting (or providing) ANSI text. If the device just stores bytes blindly without implying any particular format, you can do what you like - in this case, just always use UTF8.

Comment: Should I use `Encoding.Default` both to `reading` as to `writing` into the card?

Comment: That question shows you didn't get what he's saying. If ASCII only supports 128 characters - how's it supposed to be any good for writing the special characters you need?

Comment: @Ghaleon Ideally you should find out exactly which code page the card is using and specify it exactly - but whatever it is, you *will* need to specify it for *both* reading AND writing. When you read, the string will be converted from ANSI to Unicode and will also need to be converted back to ANSI when you write a string to the card.

Comment: Got ya ! @ThorstenDittmar ! I'll take a look at Matthew's link to learn about the encods ! Wich one do you recommend?

Comment: @Ghaleon Note the last paragraph that I just added to my answer. If your device doesn't care what the data is, just use UTF8 when reading AND writing data to it. If you have legacy text encoded using ANSI, only then do you need to use ANSI code pages.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I just tried `utf8`. and the value i got from the reading was totally messed up ;\

Comment: @Ghaleon Does that mean that *something else* is writing the data to the card? Or is it data that you wrote yourself earlier? If it is only *your* software that is writing to the card it should be ok to use UTF8 everywhere (but you might have some bad data you wrote to the card previously); otherwise, you will have to use the format that the "other" software uses (likely ANSI).

Comment: @MatthewWatson I guess it's OK using  the same encode to read/write. I just getting some `/0/0//0/0/0/0/0/0/` after the value, what is this ? spaces?

Comment: @Ghaleon It really depends on what's supported by your device - if the docs don't state anything, you should be free to chose. You might consider UTF8 or even UTF16.

Comment: @Ghaleon Those look like uninitialized data which has defaulted to 0. You can use `text = text.Trim('\0');` as a quick and dirty way to get rid of such characters.

Comment: I tried to use both encode `ISO-8859-1` and `UTF-8` for read/write, plus the `Trim('\0');` and Worked GREAT :D
I'd like to thanks every single one of you guys !

Answer (score 6):

It seems like you're using characters that aren't mapped in the 7 bits ASCII, but in the "extensions" ISO-8859-1 or ISO-8859-15. You'll need to choose a specific encoding for mapping to your byte array and things should work fine;

```cs
byte[] buffer = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(txt_IDCard.Text);
```

Comment: @Ghaleon You should definitely use the same encoding for both reads and writes. If you have other systems reading/writing, the encoding obviously needs to be the same as they're using, so unless you know which encoding it is, you could first try to read data written by another system to see that the encoding is correct. Pay special attention to the euro symbol that is only available in ISO-8859-15.

Comment: Is there a big difference between`ISO-8859-1` and `utf-8` ? I tried both and both worked...

Comment: @Ghaleon Both will have those characters, but the encoding to bytes is definitely different. In other words, if you're interoperating with other systems, you'll definitely want to know which of the encodings those systems use. If not interoperating and space isn't very constrained, I'd go for UTF8 all the way.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems there:

1. ASCII supports only a limited amount of characters.
2. You're currently using two different Encodings for reading and writing.

You should write with the same Encoding as you read.

Writing

```
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(txt_IDCard.Text);
```

Reading

```
    string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
```

Comment: I did it with ASCII ;x. Should I try to `Write/Read` using a different `encoding`?

Comment: Yes - using an encoding (ASCII) that doesn't support the characters for writing the card, what do you think you'll read?

Comment: Just make sure both are the same and that you don't use ASCII.